# Change WordPress User Password From phpMyAdmin in CPanel

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I can't log into the WP Dashboard because the password I always use is incorrect. I know I can change the user info from hosting account. I logged into cPanel and went to phpMyAdmin > wp_users and proceeded to change user_pass to the appropriate password. I'm back at square 1 because I cannot log in.

Comment: Did you encrypted your password with PHP Pass when you updated it in the database? If not use [this website](http://www.catchstudio.com/labs/password-generator/) to generate the PHPPass hash.

Answer (score 1):

you need select md5 encryption, in the function table you select md5, because wordpress use this encryption method for the password.

Image http://tinyurl.com/q3ec792

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the [instruction](https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password#Through_phpMyAdmin):

**Through phpMyAdmin**

This article is for those who have phpMyAdmin access to their database.

Note: use phpMyAdmin at your own risk. If you doubt your ability to use it, seek further advice. WordPress is not responsible for loss of data.

- Begin by logging into phpMyAdmin and clicking **databases**.
- A list of databases will appear. Click your **WordPress database**.
- All the tables in your database will appear. If not, click **Structure**.
- Look for **wp_users** in the **Table** column.
- Click on the icon for browse.
- Locate your **Username** under **user_login**
- Click **edit** (may look like a pencil icon in some versions of
  phpMyAdmin)
- Your **user_id** will be shown, click on **Edit**
- Next to the **user_pass** is a long list of numbers and letters.
- Select and delete these and type in your new password.
- Type in the password you want to use. Just type it in normally, but
  remember, it is **case-sensitive**.
- In this example, the new password will be '**rabbitseatcarrots**'
- Once you have done that, click the dropdown menu indicated, and
  select **MD5** from the menu.
- Check that your password is actually correct, and that **MD5** is in the
  box.
- Click the '**Go**' button to the bottom right.
- Test the new password on the login screen. If it doesn't work, check
  that you've followed these instructions exactly.